# How to wait for/check ajax response before another action

Tags: jquery, ajax, expressionengine

I have a page that has 2 forms. 1 form updates data of an entry and the other is used to email that data to a selection of recipients.

When submitting the email form I need it to update a field of the entry form then save that data via AJAX then send itself.
It's mostly working but I feel the delay is where things could do with improvment as, obviously if the save takes longer than 1000ms the data is lost.
Also this seems to cause a lot of recursion in firefox (not tested others).

```
$('#emailSend').click(function(){
    preventDefault();
    $('#status').val('Live');
    $('#submitChanges').click();
    $(this).delay(1000).click();
});


$('#entryData').ajaxForm(function() { 

});
```

How would I check the data saved before proceeding to '$(this).click();'?

I'm using expressionengine and jquery.forms plugin

Thanks

Comment: ajax functions have a callback `$.ajax({}).done(function(){//runs after ajax call});`

Comment: honestly you might want to consider taking a step back and spending some time on a site like https://www.codecademy.com/learn

Comment: you have to add   async: false  to ajax options  like this $.ajax({type: "POST",url:"yourpage",data:"your data",async: false,success:function(result){/*do some thing*/}})

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: Thanks I got this:

`$('#emailSend').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#status').val('Live');
     $('#entryData').ajaxSubmit(function(){
      $.ajax({}).done(function(){
       $('#emailSend').click();
       location.reload(true);
      });
        });
    });`